# One box changing colour at a time rather than two?

Tags: javascript, html, css, clock

I'm trying to make something that will change background colour when at a certain minute, this I have done. However I want to have five boxes that change colour at different times.

Example;
Box 1 changes to yellow at any minute ending in 0
Box 1 changes to green at any minute ending in 1
Box 1 default is a blue-ish colour

Box 2 changes to yellow at any minute ending in 1
Box 2 changes to green at any minute ending in 2
Box 2 default is a blue-ish colour

And so on for the full 5 boxes, and this is the code I have for the first;

```
<script>
function clock()
{
setInterval(
function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    var box = document.getElementById("box");

    switch(m % 10)
    {
        case 4:
            box.style.background = "ffc000";
            break;
        case 5:
            box.style.background = "34db00";
            break;
        case 9:
            box.style.background = "ffc000";
            break;
        case 0:
            box.style.background = "34db00";
            break;
        default:
            box.style.background = "0093ff";
    }
}, 1000);   
}
</script>

<center>


<body onload="clock()">
<div id="box" style="width:30%; height:150px; background: 0093ff; float: left; border-radius:25px;">


<p>
<p style="color:white">

<body vlink="white">
<body link="white">


<table border="0">
<tr>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
<td><a href="Shop Url" target="iframe1">Shop Name</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

</p>



</div>
</body>
```

My problem is that only one box will change colour, when two should have a different colour at the same time. (One yellow and one green).

I'm not sure if I explained clearly here or not but I tried to get everything in that I could.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have three body tags in a document. And `<center>` was deprecated 100 year ago, don't use it, use CSS.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. What exactly prevents you from adding the other boxes and changing their color to whatever you want?

Comment: Aha, yeah, this is something I was given to make as a little help on another site. I'll be fixing that up now, thanks!

@Juhana, I'm able to put the boxes in but they don't change colour, but because they change at certain minutes it is preventing the other boxes from changing colour.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but I meant something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7RYDe/ (they change every second for the demo)

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a switch block. The purpose of the switch block is to select one alternative from various possibilites, but you're saying you want possibly multiple criteria to match. Just replace your switch block with a series of if statements (so multiple ones can apply)